# Error executing hql script using spark-sql

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to insert data into a table in Hive but I want to execute it as a spark-sql job and getting errors. Instead of `hive -f insert_script` I want to do `spark-sql -f insert_script`. Here is a snippet of my insert code

```
set spark.hadoop.hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=true;
set spark.hadoop.hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;
set tez.am.resource.memory.mb=4098;
set spark.hadoop.hive.tez.container.size=4098;
set spark.hadoop.hive.optimize.sort.dynamic.partition=false;

INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE stackdatabase.stacktable
Partition(year, month, day, job_id)
SELECT
tickersymbol,
S&Ptickersymbol,
DOWticersymbol,
processdate,
....
...
year, 
month, 
day, 
job_id
FROM stackdatabase.bkp_stacktable
```

Here is the error message

org.apache.spark.SparkException: Dynamic partition strict mode requires at least one static partition column. To turn this off set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict

```
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertHiveTableValidation.checkDynamicPartitioning(InsertHiveTableValidation.scala:69)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertHiveTableValidation.apply(InsertHiveTableValidation.scala:50)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.doHiveSpecificValidationIfInsertIsForHiveTable(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:236)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:86)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:108)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:106)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.executeCollect(commands.scala:120)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$logicalPlan$1(Dataset.scala:230)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$withAction$1(Dataset.scala:3751)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker$.withTracker(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:107)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withTracker(SQLExecution.scala:232)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.executeQuery$1(SQLExecution.scala:110)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$6(SQLExecution.scala:135)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker$.withTracker(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:107)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withTracker(SQLExecution.scala:232)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$5(SQLExecution.scala:135)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:253)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:134)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:775)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:68)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3749)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.<init>(Dataset.scala:230)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.$anonfun$ofRows$2(Dataset.scala:101)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:775)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:98)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.$anonfun$sql$1(SparkSession.scala:618)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:775)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:613)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.sql(SQLContext.scala:650)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.SparkSQLDriver.run(SparkSQLDriver.scala:67)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.SparkSQLCLIDriver.processCmd(SparkSQLCLIDriver.scala:381)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.SparkSQLCLIDriver.$anonfun$processLine$1(SparkSQLCLIDriver.scala:500)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.SparkSQLCLIDriver.$anonfun$processLine$1$adapted(SparkSQLCLIDriver.scala:494)

    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:941)

    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:941)

    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1429)

    at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach(IterableLike.scala:74)

    at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach$(IterableLike.scala:73)

    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:56)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.SparkSQLCLIDriver.processLine(SparkSQLCLIDriver.scala:494)

    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:336)

    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processReader(CliDriver.java:474)

    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processFile(CliDriver.java:490)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.SparkSQLCLIDriver$.main(SparkSQLCLIDriver.scala:210)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.SparkSQLCLIDriver.main(SparkSQLCLIDriver.scala)

    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)

    at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)

    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:959)

    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)

    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:203)

    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:90)

    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1047)

    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1056)

    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

org.apache.spark.SparkException: Dynamic partition strict mode requires at least one static partition column. To turn this off set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict

```
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertHiveTableValidation.checkDynamicPartitioning(InsertHiveTableValidation.scala:69)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertHiveTableValidation.apply(InsertHiveTableValidation.scala:50)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.doHiveSpecificValidationIfInsertIsForHiveTable(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:236)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:86)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:108)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:106)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.executeCollect(commands.scala:120)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$logicalPlan$1(Dataset.scala:230)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$withAction$1(Dataset.scala:3751)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker$.withTracker(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:107)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withTracker(SQLExecution.scala:232)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.executeQuery$1(SQLExecution.scala:110)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$6(SQLExecution.scala:135)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker$.withTracker(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:107)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withTracker(SQLExecution.scala:232)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$5(SQLExecution.scala:135)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:253)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:134)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:775)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:68)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3749)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.<init>(Dataset.scala:230)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.$anonfun$ofRows$2(Dataset.scala:101)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:775)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:98)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.$anonfun$sql$1(SparkSession.scala:618)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:775)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:613)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.sql(SQLContext.scala:650)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.SparkSQLDriver.run(SparkSQLDriver.scala:67)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.SparkSQLCLIDriver.processCmd(SparkSQLCLIDriver.scala:381)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.SparkSQLCLIDriver.$anonfun$processLine$1(SparkSQLCLIDriver.scala:500)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.SparkSQLCLIDriver.$anonfun$processLine$1$adapted(SparkSQLCLIDriver.scala:494)

    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:941)

    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:941)

    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1429)

    at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach(IterableLike.scala:74)

    at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach$(IterableLike.scala:73)

    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:56)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.SparkSQLCLIDriver.processLine(SparkSQLCLIDriver.scala:494)

    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:336)

    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processReader(CliDriver.java:474)

    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processFile(CliDriver.java:490)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.SparkSQLCLIDriver$.main(SparkSQLCLIDriver.scala:210)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.SparkSQLCLIDriver.main(SparkSQLCLIDriver.scala)

    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)

    at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)

    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:959)

    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)

    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:203)

    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:90)

    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1047)

    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1056)

    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

Comment: Cann you pls make sure last columns in your select statement are `year, month, day, job_id`?

Comment: yes, the last columns are `year, month, day, job_id` I've updated the code.

Comment: You probably meant your very first line to be `set spark.hadoop.hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true` ? (Notice no ...mode)

Comment: hey @mazaneicha still does not work

Comment: can you insert a static partition? if no, then there is some issue with environment. if yes, then add one strict partition, then another. see where it breaks and update us pls